# Lookup style of POJO object in CSS

Tags: css, javafx, pojo

A helper `Label` that doesn't really fit in `fxml`, so it is created (as a POJO) and attached at `initialize()` step.

This is straightforward in fxml:

stylesheet.css:  `.my-label { -fx-font-size: 12px; }`

my_view.fxml:  `<Label fx:id="label" styleClass="my-label" />`

Or in POJO locally: `label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12px;");`

What is the right way to define Label in POJO, but move style to css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the style class:

```
label.getStyleClass().add("my-label");
```

and then use the same CSS you have for your FXML example.

Comment: What if my style is `.my-top-panel > .my-label { -fx-font-size: 12px; }`? Sorry for a folowup question.

Comment: @Stepan Does that make any difference? The `.my-label` selector in the CSS is still trying to match something with a style class of `"my-label"`, so with the code above, if `label` is a direct child of a parent that has a CSS class of `"my-top-panel"`, the style will be applied. The Java code I posted is identical to the FXML attribute `styleClass="my-label"`.